# How to create RowEncoder to map Tuple<A,Row> to Row?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataset where I have grouped and reduced my data according to my need. I need to get rid of the tuple and only retain Tuple2::_2.
I am trying to map the dataset as follows:

```
sparkSession.read()
            .parquet("s3://stuff/*")
            .groupByKey((MapFunction<Row, Long>) value -> {
                long stamp = value.getAs("timeStamp");
                return stamp / 600000;
            }, Encoders.LONG())
            .reduceGroups((ReduceFunction<Row>) (v1, v2) -> {
                int fare1 = v1.getAs("totalFare");
                int fare2 = v2.getAs("totalFare");
                return fare1 < fare2 ? v1 : v2;
            })
            .map((MapFunction<Tuple2<Long, Row>, Row>) Tuple2::_2, RowEncoder.apply(null))
```

Can't figure out how to supply the schema to RowEncoder::apply.
I am reading a parquet file with [this](https://pastebin.com/82S3nS7N) schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up doing it this way. Basically read 1 element to get the required "ExpressionEncoder". I need the full "row" in the final output so could not go ahead with @Jacek's approach.

```
System.out.println("Starting");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
Row sampleRow = sparkSession.read().parquet(readFrom).head();
ExpressionEncoder<Row> rowEncoder = RowEncoder.apply(sampleRow.schema());

//read all elements, process and write back the result
sparkSession.read()
            .parquet(readFrom)
            .groupByKey((MapFunction<Row, Long>) value -> {
                long stamp = value.getAs("timeStamp");
                return stamp / 600000;
            }, Encoders.LONG())
            .reduceGroups((ReduceFunction<Row>) (v1, v2) -> {
                int fare1 = v1.getAs("totalFare");
                int fare2 = v2.getAs("totalFare");
                return fare1 < fare2 ? v1 : v2;
            })
            .map((MapFunction<Tuple2<Long, Row>, Row>) Tuple2::_2, rowEncoder)
            .write()
            .parquet(writeTo);
System.out.println("Done !!!!");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using Java with Spark so I can't be more specific, but...

If I'm not mistaken you only want to work with `timeStamp` and `totalFare` fields. `timeStamp` is of long type while `totalFare` is of int type.

My first recommendation would be to leave untyped `Row` to `Dataset[Long, Int]` (in Scala) using [as](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#as(org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder)) operator:

> **public  Dataset as(Encoder evidence$2)** Returns a new Dataset where each record has been mapped on to the specified type.

That way you'd avoid dealing with this unpleasant `Row` objects and your transformation would look as follows:

```
sparkSession.read()
            .parquet("s3://stuff/*")
            .as(Encoder...)  // <-- I don't know how to write a tuple of (long, int) in Java
```

Having done that, your question about `map` would get "mapped" to use `Encoders.INT()` if I'm not mistaken (trying to map my Scala thinking to Java's).

The reason I'm advocating to use `as` operator is that using `groupByKey` and `reduceGroups` feels to me as a very strong desire to leave untyped [RelationalGroupedDataset](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset) API to typed [KeyValueGroupedDataset](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset).